# Swift Generic struct conform to protocol with associatedType got "Cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'Key'" Error

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

```swift
protocol Container {
    associatedtype ItemType
    func getItem() -> ItemType
    func getItems() -> [ItemType]
}

struct TypedBackpack<TypedItemType: StringProtocol>: Container {
    func getItem() -> TypedItemType {
        return ""
    }
    
    func getItems() -> [TypedItemType] {
        return [""]
    }
}

struct KeyBackpack<Key: Sequence>: Container {
    func getItem() -> Key { //"Error: Cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'Key'"
        return ""       
    }
    func getItems() -> [Key] { //"Error: Cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'Key'"
        return [""]
    }
}
```

I got "Error: Cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'Key'" for "getItem()" and "getItems()" functions in KeyBackPack.
However, TypedBackPack is working fine.

If I change KeyBackPack to:

```swift
struct KeyBackpack<Key: StringProtocol>: Container {
    func getItem() -> Key {
        return ""       
    }
    func getItems() -> [Key] { 
        return [""]
    }
}
```

Everything works fine. So the problem is "<Key: Sequence>". Can anybody tell me why <Key: StringProtocol> works fine but <Key: Sequence> doesn't?

Comment: String conforms to both Sequence and StringProtocol. But only StringProtocol works. Very strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your declarations, I am able to use any `Sequence` as the type parameter of `KeyBackpack`, and `getItem` will return an instance of that type.

So in theory, I could do this:

```
let intArray = KeyBackpack<[Int]>().getItem()
```

`[Int]` if obviously a `Sequence`, and `getItem` should give me an `[Int]`. However, what `getItem` actually returns, is an empty string! Clearly that does not make sense!

Why does `Key: StringProtocol` work then?

This is because [`StringProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol) inherits from [`ExpressibleByStringInterpolation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebystringinterpolation), which in turn inherits from [`ExpressibleByStringLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebystringliteral).

This means that you can implicitly convert a *string literal* to `Key`, because `Key` conforms to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`.

In more concrete terms, `StringProtocol` inherits the requirement [`init(stringLiteral:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebystringliteral/2294174-init) from `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, and the compiler automatically translates `return ""` to a call to that initialiser. You can think of this as:

```
return Key(stringLiteral: "")
```

This also means that if you return something other than a string literal, `Key: StringProtocol` would not have worked. e.g.

```
let s = "" // here the type of "s" is inferred to be String 
return s // "cannot convert type..." error because "s" is not a string literal, nor of type "Key"
```

Comment: Thanks. You answer convince me. Initially I thought as long as String confirms to Sequence, it should work but turns out Compiler will check if it there is a init to initiate string literal to the specified protocol.

Comment: @JamesWang I'm not sure you understand correctly. In `getItem`, you are not supposed to just return anything _of your choice_ that conforms to `Sequence`, or `StringProtocol`. You are supposed to return specifically `Key`, which is something that conforms to `StringProtocol` or `Sequence` _not of your choice_. It just so happens that in the case of `Key: StringProtocol`, `Key` also conforms to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`. The compiler checks for this protocol which guarantees the initialiser, not the initialiser itself. Because of this initialiser, a `Key` is created and returned.

Comment: @JamesWang Note that it is an instance of `Key` that is created from the string literal, not a protocol type. You can't make instances of protocol types.